# Does Ubuntu turn off Wireless device when on standby mode

Tags: wireless

I have a question. I am using an Intel Compute Stick pre installed with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit using a remote access software. And when the Compute Stick is sitting idle the Compute Stick disconnects from the wireless network and I need to hard reboot the stick to work. Does Ubuntu have a power saving option that turns off the Wifi to save power or turns off the Wifi connection when the stick goes on standby? If yes, is there a way to disable it.

TIA

Comment: There is suspend if inactive in the __system settings__.

Answer (score 0):

Suspend/Hibernate/Resume all are handled by the scripts in the `pm-utils` package (`dpkg -L pm-utils`). Begin with `/usr/share/doc/pm-utils/README`.